# Retrieving stripe account info

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Using Stripe's API with PHP. I'm trying to get the "last4" value from this test object

```html
$customers = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve("cus_8MfE5OY7uZb8qd");

Stripe\Customer JSON: {
  "id": "cus_8MfE5OY7uZb8qd",
  "object": "customer",
  "account_balance": 0,
  "created": 1462014302,
  "currency": "gbp",
  "default_source": "card_185vu8E5mWaZh4R5u4vxBYwJ",
  "delinquent": false,
  "description": null,
  "discount": null,
  "email": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "shipping": null,
  "sources": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "card_185vu8E5mWaZh4R5u4vxBYwJ",
        "object": "card",
        "address_city": null,
        "address_country": null,
        "address_line1": null,
        "address_line1_check": null,
        "address_line2": null,
        "address_state": null,
        "address_zip": null,
        "address_zip_check": null,
        "brand": "Visa",
        "country": "US",
        "customer": "cus_8MfE5OY7uZb8qd",
        "cvc_check": "pass",
        "dynamic_last4": null,
        "exp_month": 2,
        "exp_year": 2020,
        "funding": "credit",
        "last4": "4242",
        "metadata": {
        },
        "name": "stu@blue-caterpillar.co.uk",
        "tokenization_method": null
      }
    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 1,
    "url": "/v1/customers/cus_8MfE5OY7uZb8qd/sources"
  }
}
```

I can get all the data up to the sources by using

```
print $customers->description;
```

When I get to the data, this obviously returns an array:

```
print $customers->sources->data;
```

I've tried a few things to try and get the "last4" value, but no luck. Can someone point me in the right direction please? Thanks!

Comment: `print $customers->sources->data['last4'];` this didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$customers->sources->data` is an Array, and its first element is the object that contains the `last4` you're looking for.

You should be able to get it with:

```
print $customers->sources->data[0]->last4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pointing to "last4" as it is an another object?

```
 echo $customers->sources->data->last4
```